# How do I check if a file path, or its content as a string, have any type errors?

Tags: typescript

As per the title, I need a way of knowing if a specific file/code has any type errors. I couldn't the right API for this, is there any?

Comment: You can use a regex to check the string.

Comment: code can't be parsed with regexes, besides what does that tell me about the presence of errors?

Comment: Can you put more information? Example or existing code.

Comment: What more information do you need? Give any typescript file or code I want to know if it contains any type errors.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that errors can be detected like this:

```
const {Project} = require ( 'ts-simple-ast' );

const project = new Project ({
  tsConfigFilePath: 'tsconfig.json',
  addFilesFromTsConfig: false
});

project.addExistingSourceFiles ( 'dst/index.d.ts' );

const hasErrors = !!project.getPreEmitDiagnostics ().length;
```

Comment: You might be interested in [this](https://github.com/qurhub/qur-typetest) library as well

Comment: Thanks, I'll check it out.